How can I create a extension from the interface inside of a external npm package in typescript?
in react-native typescript, I use a npm called react-native-sqlite-storage, that npm has a interface like this inside its node_modules
export interface SQLiteDatabase {
    dbname: string;

    transaction(scope: (tx: Transaction) => void): Promise<Transaction>;
    //....
}

now I have a variable with this type
let db: SQLite.SQLiteDatabase

now, I want to create a function that run on that type, same as swift's extension, so I can do it like this
db.query('SELECT * FROM users;')

How can I do that?
Here's what I did, I create a file called sqlite.d.ts with this code
import 'react-native-sqlite-storage';

declare module 'react-native-sqlite-storage' {
    interface SQLiteDatabase {
        query(statement: string, params?: any[]): Promise<[ResultSet]>;
    }
}

Now in my sqliteExtension.ts file, I have this code
import SQLite, { SQLiteDatabase, ResultSet } from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';

SQLite.SQLiteDatabase.prototype.query = function (statement: string, params?: any[]): Promise<[ResultSet]> {
    return this.executeSql(statement, params);
};

now in that sqliteExtension.ts file, I'm getting an error on SQLite.SQLiteDatabase saying
Property 'SQLiteDatabase' does not exist on type 'typeof import("project_path/node_modules/@types/react-native-sqlite-storage/index")'

I also tried to extend the interface directly like this
SQLiteDatabase.prototype.query = function (statement: string, params?: any[]): Promise<[ResultSet]> {
   //...
}

but I get a different error saying
'SQLiteDatabase' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

how can I do that? is there another way to achieve this?
